# ".fileprovider" doesn't get recognized

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-manifest, android-fileprovider

I am trying to set up a fileprovider to access images taken with an Intent.
But while trying to define it in the manifest, the name doesn't get recognized.
It is the ..."fileprovider" in the third line that is the problem.

```
<provider
            android:authorities="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:name="com.mobila.project.today.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

as I understand the part before .fileprovider should match my package. But its name looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mobila.project.today">
```

How can i resolve this? Is there a workaround for using a fileprovider where I can save the pictures directly in an ArrayList for example?

Comment: ??? What is the problem? They are equal. And no it does not have to be equal to package name.

Comment: You have the `authorities` and `name` attributes values' switched. That is, they should be `android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"` and `android:authorities="com.mobila.project.today.fileprovider"`.

Comment: Good catch @Mike M. Why didnt i see that ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much @MikeM. !